# Run length encoding on binary files in C

Tags: c, binary-data, run-length-encoding

I wrote this function that performs a slightly modified variation of run-length encoding on text files in C.
I'm trying to generalize it to binary files but I have no experience working with them. I understand that, while I can compare bytes of binary data much the same way I can compare `char`s from a text file, I am not sure how to go about printing the number of occurrences of a byte to the compressed version like I do in the code below.

A note on the type of RLE I'm using: bytes that occur more than once in a row are duplicated to signal the next-to-come number is in fact the number of occurrences vs just a number following the character in the file. For occurrences longer than one digit, they are broken down into runs that are 9 occurrences long.

For example, `aaaaaaaaaaabccccc` becomes `aa9aa2bcc5`.

Here's my code:

```
char* encode(char* str)
{
    char* ret = calloc(2 * strlen(str) + 1, 1);
    size_t retIdx = 0, inIdx = 0;
    while (str[inIdx]) {
        size_t count = 1;
        size_t contIdx = inIdx;
        while (str[inIdx] == str[++contIdx]) {
            count++;
        }
        size_t tmpCount = count;

        // break down counts with 2 or more digits into counts ≤ 9
        while (tmpCount > 9) {
            tmpCount -= 9;
            ret[retIdx++] = str[inIdx];
            ret[retIdx++] = str[inIdx];
            ret[retIdx++] = '9';
        }

        char tmp[2];

        ret[retIdx++] = str[inIdx];
        if (tmpCount > 1) {
            // repeat character (this tells the decompressor that the next digit
            // is in fact the # of consecutive occurrences of this char)
            ret[retIdx++] = str[inIdx];
            // convert single-digit count to string
            snprintf(tmp, 2, "%ld", tmpCount);
            ret[retIdx++] = tmp[0];
        }

        inIdx += count;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

What changes are in order to adapt this to a binary stream? The first problem I see is with the `snprintf` call since it's operating using a text format. Something that rings a bell is also the way I'm handling the multiple-digit occurrence runs. We're not working in base 10 anymore so that has to change, I'm just unsure how having almost never worked with binary data.

Comment: For one thing, if you go to binary you are no longer limited to digits of '0' to '9'. You can use the full 0 to 255 range of the byte value for your repetition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to address 2 problems:

- you cannot use any str-related functions, because C strings do not deal well with `'\0'`. So for example, `strlen` will return the index of the 1st 0x0 byte in a string. The length of the input must be passed in as an additional parameter: `char *encode(char *start, size_t length)`
- your output cannot have an implicit length of `strlen(ret)`, because there may be extra 0-bytes sprinkled about in the output. You again need an extra parameter: `size_t encode(char *start, size_t length, char *output)` (this version would require the `output` buffer to be reserved externally, with a size of at least `length*2`, and return the length of the encoded string)

The rest of the code, assuming it was working before, should continue to work correctly now. If you want to go beyond base-10, and for instance use base-256 for greater compression, you would only need to change the constant in the break-things-up loop (from `9` to `255`), and replace the `snprintf` as follows:

```
    // before
    snprintf(tmp, 2, "%ld", tmpCount);
    ret[retIdx++] = tmp[0];

    // after: much easier
    ret[retIdx++] = tmpCount;
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it has to do with the way ascii chars are encoded but I'll ask just to make sure... Why can I avoid the `snprintf` trick if I use base 255?

Comment: In the binary version, you store unsigned ints directly into bytes: `5` is stored as `5`. In the text version, you are using ASCII character codes: `5` is stored as `'0' + 5 = 53 = '5'`. So this would be, to me, an improvement of the text version: `ret[retIdx++] = '0' + tmpCount;`

Comment: Thank you. One last question: do the buffer need any modifications done to them? I saw someone using `unsigned char` instead of `char` for handling binary data. Someone used `uint8_t` as well. Is there any merit to it?

Comment: It communicates intent better - I would indeed prefer `uint8_t` to `char`. It is by no means necessary for the program to be correct; but it is certainly more maintainable by humans.

Comment: Thank you, your answer (and subsequent answers) was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

A few ideas that can be useful to you:

- one simple method to generalize RLE to binary data is to use a bit-based compression. For example the bit sequence `00000000011111100111` can be translated to the sequence `0 9623`. Since the binary alphabet is composed by only two symbols, you need to only store the first bit value (this can be as simple as storing it in the very first bit) and then the number of the contiguous equal values. Arbitrarily large integers can be stored in a binary format using [Elias gamma coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elias_gamma_coding). Extra padding can be added to fit the entire sequence nicely into an integer number of bytes. So using this method, the above sequence can be encoded like this:

```
00000000011111100111 -> 0 0001001 00110 010 011
                        ^    ^      ^    ^   ^
                first bit    9      6    2   3
```

- If you want to keep it byte based, one idea is to consider all the even bytes frequencies (interpreted as an unsigned char) and all the odd bytes the values. If one byte occur more than 255 times, than you can just repeat it. This can be very inefficient, though, but it is definitively simple to implement, and it might be good enough if you can make some assumptions on the input.
- Also, you can consider moving out from RLE and implement [Huffman's coding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) or other sophisticated algorithms (e.g. [LZW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lempel%E2%80%93Ziv%E2%80%93Welch)).

Implementation wise, i think [tucuxi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67483409/6671739) already gave you some hints.

Comment: Suggestion #1 has very nice insights on bit-based RLE - although I doubt that was the intent behind OP's question. Suggestion #2 is a simple scheme to improve speed if there are lots of duplicates, and #3 is a good starting point into better compression.